# Шаблонная виртуальная функция

Tags: c++, c++11

Поясните, пожалуйста, почему нельзя создать виртуальную шаблонную функцию?

Нашел следующее [объяснение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27709454/4295626):

> Member function templates cannot be declared virtual. This constraint
>   is imposed because the usual implementation of the virtual function
>   call mechanism uses a fixed-size table with one entry per virtual
>   function. However, the number of instantiations of a member function
>   template is not fixed until the entire program has been translated.
>   Hence, supporting virtual member function templates would require
>   support for a whole new kind of mechanism in C++ compilers and
>   linkers. In contrast, the ordinary members of class templates can be
>   virtual because their number is fixed when a class is instantiated

То есть теоретически такой функционал реализовать можно, но это потребует серьезного изменения принципов работы существующих компилятор и линковщиков. Или есть и другие причины?

Comment: Отличный вопрос, кстати!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Простой ответ:

В С++ шаблон функции не является функцией, поэтому шаблон не может быть виртуальным.

В C#/Java/etc используются не шаблоны, а generics. Generic-функция это (одна) функция, поэтому там такой проблемы нет.

#### Сложный ответ:

В С++ виртуальные функции сделаны так, что их количество прописано в определении базового класса.
Это позволяет присвоить функции некоторый индекс в базовом классе и быстро находить ее по этому индексу.

```
struct Base {            
  func_t* vft;  // скрытый член класса - массив виртуальных функций
  virtual void f();   
};                    

Base* x = new Derived;         
x->f();
// компилируется в
x->vft[0]();
```

Если шаблоны будут виртуальными, то вместо перечисления функций в базовом классе надо искать все подстановки шаблона при вызовах функции.
Для этого вместо индексов надо использовать имена, и искать эти имена в хеш-таблице.

```
struct Base {            
  hash_map<string, func_t> vft;  // скрытый член класса - хеш-таблица виртуальных функций
  template<typename T> virtual void f();   
};                    

Base* x = new Derived;         
x->f<int>();
// компилируется в
x->vft["f<int>"]();
```

Скорость вызова значительно упадет, т.к. надо будет разрешать коллизии.

Можно использовать идеальную хеш-функцию (без коллизий).

```
struct Base {            
  func_t* vft;  // скрытый член класса - массив (sic!) виртуальных функций
  virtual void f();   
};                    

Base* x = new Derived;         
x->f();
// компилируется в
x->vft[ideal_hash("f<int>")]();
// ideal_hash(name) выдает индекс массива, без коллизий
```

Но из-за динамической линковки (.so/.dll) весь исходный код программы недоступен, и при каждой загрузке SO/DLL надо останавливать всю программу, менять хеш-функцию и перестраивать все таблицы, чтобы учитывались типы, которые добавились в этой SO/DLL.

---

Использование **JIT-компилятора** может заменять виртуальные вызовы на обычные, и тогда никаких проблем с производительностью вызова не будет.

```
// вместо x->f(); генерируется
x->Derived::f();
// если доказано что тут может быть только Derived
```

Но девиртуализация работает только если количество классов мало, и на данный момент эффективных JIT-компиляторов нет. (Те что есть, например в LLVM, не показывают хороших результатов.)

Comment: По поводу простого ответа — это отсылка к стандарту, а не к мотивации. По поводу сложного ответа — что мешает включить в VMT все реально существующие в коде инстанциации? (Оставляя в стороне вопрос о том, что VMT не является нормативной.)

Comment: Не-не :) Динамической линковки нет в стандарте. Кроме того, что мешает пользоваться для шаблонов двойной косвенностью? VMT можно оставить для нешаблонных методов.

Comment: Подождите, а что происходит с .so в случае, когда в .so определён внутренний тип `local`, и инстанциируется `vector<local>`? Где лежит код `vector<local>`?

Comment: @VladD чтобы `vector<local>` инстанцировался, `local` должен быть доступен на момент компиляции.

Comment: @alexolut: Это немного подрывает аргументацию данного ответа, не так ли?

Comment: @Abyx: То есть, код `vector<local>` находится в .so? Тогда почему бы не сделать так, что код `c.f<T>` находится локально в каждом из модулей, содержащих этот вызов? И проводить вызов не через VMT. (Этот случай легко отличим для компилятора.)

Comment: @Abyx: Re/update: Компилятор может вполне прокешировать lookup в таблицу, так что performance hit будет довольно редко.

Comment: @Abyx, то есть JIT-компилятор решил бы данную проблему, но, как я понимаю, встает другой вопрос - даст ли JIT существенные преимущества, если его реализовать, или игра не стоит свеч?

Comment: @Abyx: Но по идее какой-нибудь HotSpot собирает данные во время пробега и перекомпилирует функцию, когда соберёт достаточно информации. Так что JIT вполне себе может.

Comment: @Abyx: Окей, ещё одна идея. А почему бы не иметь много таблиц виртуальных методов, для каждого из шаблонных аргументов? Какая именно таблица нужна, компилятор видит в compile time. (Пытаюсь сообразить, можно ли это скрестить с динамической компоновкой.)

Answer (score 7):

Это невозможно сделать в рамках существующих реализаций С++. Так как виртуальные функции реализованы через таблицы указателей на них, компилятор должен иметь возможность сгенерировать функцию при ее определении - чтобы получить указатель.

Так как код шаблонных функций генерируется только при инстанциировании шаблона, компилятор не может заполнить таблицу - у него просто нет указателя.

Шаблонные виртуальные функции потребовали бы полного пересмотра подхода к полиморфизму, и для полной реализации потребовали бы "исполняющей машины" - примерно как Java или С#.

Простой пример (не компилирующийся, естественно):

```
// file base.h
struct Base {
    template <class T>
    virtual void foo(T ) { }
};

// file derived.h
#include <base.h>
struct Derived : Base {
   template <class T>
   virtual void foo(T ) { };
};

// file foo.cpp 
#include <base.h>
void foo(Base* b) {
    base->foo(42);
}

// file main.cpp
#include <derived.h>
int main() {
    Base* d = new Derived;
    foo(d);
}
```

В приведенном примере очевидно, что компилятор не может сформировать правильный вызов функции `foo()`.

В комментариях приводится такой аргумент - "А давайте заставим пользователя включать все заголовки всех потомков перед использованием шаблонной функции, а компилятор генерировать все таблицы виртуальных методов для всего дерева base которое он увидел in-place". Но у переданного `foo()` указателя **уже** должны быть сформированная таблица. Переформировать ее уже не получится!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37437/discussion-on-answer-by-sergeya---).